# Unable to locate package php gd Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php, php-gd

I'm trying to deploy my project with Heroku and I need to install gd on my server.
My composer file structure looks

```
  "require": {
          "ext-gd": "*",
}
```

When I making `composer update` i catch the following message.

```
The requested PHP extension ext-gd * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
```

Ok, I enter the following command to install

```
apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

My installed php version is 7.3.14 even I writing exact version no. I catch the following message:

```
Reading package lists..Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-gd'
```

The following suggestion of

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

also won't help.

I've read a lot of data on this issue but either isn't helped yet.

Comment: If you use PHP 7.3, why did you try to install an extension for PHP 7.0?

Comment: As I wrote, it's no sense which version I've written, the error the same

Answer (score -1):

try install gd extension by composer with `--ignore-platform-reqs` key if it need:

```
composer require ext-gd
```

and if you are using **docker**:

1) execute this for install gd extension:

```
docker-php-ext-install gd
```

2) and for enable extension on docker:

```
docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: I'm not using docker.
This also doesn't help

Comment: There is no composer package to install GD from, that's a PHP extension